# How to use fully functional JsonPath in RobotFramework?

Tags: json, robotframework, jsonpath

Could you please recommend how to use JsonPath in the Robot Framework?
It should supports multi-level query as following:

```
$.items[?(@.status.name="closed")].name
```

I'm seeking the way to make following work:

```
*** Variables ***
${json}         {"items":[{"name":"item1","status":{"id":1,"name":"opened"}},{"name":"item2","status":{"id":2,"name":"closed"}}]}
${json_path}    $.items[?(@.status.name="closed")].name
*** Test Cases ***
Get closed item
    ${names}=    Get Json Items    ${json}    ${json_path}
    Should be equal    ${names[0]}    item2
```

someting like this

Comment: what is `$.items`? It doesn't look like a robot variable.

Comment: yes. it is not. it is a part of jsonpath query pointing to the items array at the root of the json

Comment: please show an example of a robot test where you're creating and using one of these objects.

Comment: updated the question with an example

Comment: where does the keyword `Get Json Items` come from, or is it a keyword you wrote? Are you asking how to write that keyword?

Comment: Yes. I do need some library to use jsonpath in the RF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This RF code does what you need but ONLY for provided json structure. From my point of view you should play with `Get Json Value` and prepare keywords you need. BTW, it is obvious that such json/string handling in RF is a bit complicated so I would rather write small Python library with keywords you need.

```
*** Settings ***
Library            Collections
Library            HttpLibrary.HTTP

*** Variables ***
${json}         {"items":[{"name":"item1","status":{"id":1,"name":"opened"}},{"name":"item2","status":{"id":2,"name":"closed"}}]}
${name}    ${EMPTY}
${result}    ${EMPTY}

*** Test Cases ***
Get Closed Item
    ${name}    Get Name By Status    ${json}    closed
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${name}    item2
    ${name}    Get Name By Status    ${json}    opened
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${name}    item1

*** Keywords ***
Get Name By Status
    [Arguments]    ${json}    ${status}
    [Return]    ${result}
    ${json}    Parse Json    ${json}
    :FOR    ${item}    IN    @{json["items"]}
    \    ${item}    Stringify Json    ${item}
    \    ${name}    Get Json Value    ${item}    /name
    \    ${name}    Parse Json    ${name}
    \    ${status_name}    Get Json Value    ${item}    /status/name
    \    ${status_name}    Parse Json    ${status_name}
    \    ${result}    Set Variable If    '${status_name}' == '${status}'    ${name}    ${result}
```

Edit: based on comment below I would go for such python based code.

`JsonpathLibrary.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import jsonpath

class JsonpathLibrary(object):

    def get_items_by_path(self, json_string, json_path):
        json_object = json.loads(json_string)
        match_object = jsonpath.jsonpath(json_object, json_path)
        match_string = json.dumps(match_object[0])
        return match_string
```

RF code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library            JsonpathLibrary.py

*** Variables ***
${json}         {"items":[{"name":"item1","status":{"id":1,"name":"opened"}},{"name":"item2","status":{"id":2,"name":"closed"}}]}
${json_path}    $.items[?(@.status.name=="closed")].name

*** Test Cases ***
Some Descriptive Name Here
    ${name}    Get Items By Path    ${json}    ${json_path}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${name}    "item2"
```

Comment: thanks for an answer, but this is not what i need. the structure can changes (its about integration testing) and such solution is not appropriate. so i need to use jsonpath/objectpath

Comment: OK, I've tried to do it by python's jsonpath. `pip install jsonpath`

Comment: thank you! that's works! i did something similar, but my mistake was - i used jsonpath_rw instead of jsonpath (google lied to me) - and the jsonpath_rw didn't supports "?(" constructions which is needed to me!

Comment: Then lucky me. I had no idea what jsonpath is before your qustion and I've googled out the solution in few minutes. I was only struggling with that jsonpath variable - you definitely noticed the double = sign. Some random jsonpath online validator helped. Anyway I'm glad it works.

Comment: i discovered it few days ago :) but seems like it does not supports combined conditions :(

Comment: Oh... that's a pity. So you'll need to write some extra python code. But I believe it's still doable.

Comment: yes. it is. i made an ObjectPath library - it have some syntax distinction but supports combined conditions!