# How to get all parent and child id, name values from sample json dictionary based on the type?

Tags: json, robotframework

How to retrieve id, name values where type=type1 in Robot Framework/Python. Try to use the code provided in [How to use fully functional JsonPath in RobotFramework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978952/how-to-use-fully-functional-jsonpath-in-robotframework), but the sample JSON I have is different and the solution doesn't seem to work the way I wanted.

a) Get all id, name values where type=type1
   expected result :

```
 { {'538','Test Org1'},{'236','Test Org2'}}
```

b) Get all id, name values where division.type = DivType1 for Parent Id =236
expected result:

```
{{'905',‘Test Org2 Div1’},{ '906’, ‘Test Org2 Div2’}}
```

c) Get all division  Id, name where location = Chicago under Parent Id=538

Sample Webservice Response ( used Requests Library Get Request and got below response into a variable).

```
[
{'id': '538', 'name': ‘Test Org1’, 'type': ‘type1’,
‘relationships': 
[{‘division’: {'id': '905', 'name': ‘Test Org Div1’, 'type': 
‘DivType1’}, ‘location’: ‘Chicago’}, {‘division’: {'id': '905', 
'name': ‘Test Org Div1’, 'type': ‘DivType2’}, ‘location’: 
‘NewYork’}]}, 
{'id': ’236’, 'name': ‘Test Org2’, 'type': ‘type1’, 
‘relationships': 
[{‘division’: {'id': '905', 'name': ‘Test Org2 Div1’, 'type': 
‘DivType1’}, ‘location’: ‘Atlanta’}, {‘division’: {'id': '906’, 
'name': ‘Test Org2 Div2’, 'type': ‘DivType1’}, ‘location’: 
 ‘NewYork’}]}
 ]
```

Trying to Pass the JSON object and get the list of values passing json path.

```
${RespJson}=         set variable       ${resp.json()}
${RStr}=       Convert JSON to String   ${RespJson[0]}
${ParentId}=    Get Items By Path  ${RStr}  $.(@.type=="type1")].id
log to console       ${ParentId}
```

Comment: json proveded above is invalid

Comment: At the end, I created my own keyword to extract what I want.  Thanks for looking into it.